# Accessing bits of Floating-point data - Unable to find a solution

Tags: c, floating-point

So i am stuck in what i have to write in order to get the program to print out the correct output. What it's meant to do is when i type in the number "0.15625"  it should in theory print out "0|01111100|01000000000000000000000"

But i am just confused as to how or what kind of solution i need to get the expected output.

Help would be appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct my_bitfield_t{
  int b1 : 2;
  int b2: 6;
};

union my_union_t{
  struct my_bitfield_t b;
  uint8_t i;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
  float Not_A_NUmber = NAN;
  float No_infinity = INFINITY;
  switch(argv[1]){
    case "" : printf("Input a number\n");
      break;
    case "NaN": printf("%f\n", Not_A_NUmber);
      break;
    case "Infinity": printf("%f\n", No_infinity);
      break;
    default: float value = atof(argv[1]);
      union my_union_t u;
      u.i = (int) value;
      //print individual bits
      printf("%d\n", u.b.b2);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using unions for type conversion isn't recommended any more, use `memcpy` to copy to/from a char array and then work with the bytes individually.

Comment: `switch(argv[1])` is not going to function as you wish it to unless C has changed quite a lot since I last used it regularly (C99 Standard). I think this is going to try to use the `char*` that is `argv[1]` as an integer, not a string.

Comment: @MarkRansom Any form of type-punning is implementation-dependent behavior. `union` is no worse than `memcpy()`.

Comment: `%d` prints the number in decimal, not binary.

Comment: @Barmar `memcpy` is guaranteed to work, because otherwise there'd be no compliant way to e.g. write a binary value to a file. Unfortunately I can't point to the part of the standard that allows it.

Comment: @Barmar: Some are worse and are also *undefined* behavior due to aliasing violations; others are just implementation-defined. That `float` is IEEE single and that floating point and integer bit/byte order match are fairly reasonable assumptions.

Comment: @MarkRansom: It *works*, but it's not required to give you porable data as the result.

Comment: @R.. it's better to have implementation defined behavior than undefined behavior. Those demons flying from your nose can tickle!

Comment: Back to the `switch` which requires `int` cases not `char*`. In C the (implied) string `==` test rarely works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you wanted to use type punning, you would need a `float` element in the union.

In addition, access to bits is compiler implementation defined. The first bit in a `struct` is not necessarily the MSB. It may be the LSB or any bit in the middle really...

This is true even if we assume an [IEEE 754 floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) implementation. Switching compilers may brake the bit accessing scheme.

Also, `case` can't compare strings, AFAIK... The idea of `case "NaN"` won't work.

You're actually comparing the address of the string at `argv[1]` to the address of the compiled string ("NaN") in the `data` segment of the compiled file - **these addresses will never match**.

As a last note, `atof` returns a `double`, not a float. C89 describes `strtod`, C99 adds `strtof`... `strtof` is probably the function you want, it returns a `float`.

As an added bonus, [`strtof`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtof) covers `NaN` and `Inf` in it's many variations. This will allow you to test for NaN later.

Considering these issues, your function might look like this (untested):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct my_bitfield_t {
  int b1 : 2;
  int b2 : 6;
};

union my_union_t {
  struct my_bitfield_t b;
  uint8_t i;
  uint32_t u;
  float f;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc != 2)
    goto error;
  union my_union_t u;
  u.f = strtof(argv[1], 0);
  if (isnan(u.f) || isinf(u.f)) {
    /* there are many possible NaN values, they can't fit in `switch` */
    /* the same is true for infinity (positive / negative) */
    printf("%f\n", u.f);
  } else {
    printf("%d\n", u.b.b2); /* implementation specific bit ordering */
    printf("%d\n", (u.u >> 22) & 1023);
    /* print bit by bit */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
      uint8_t bit = (u.u >> (31 - i)) & 1;
      printf("%d", bit);
      if (i == 0 || i == 8)
        printf("|");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;

error:
  printf("Input a single floating point number\n");
  return -1;
}
```